# Why has shanks never claimed any island?

Tags: one-piece

As in like Whitebeard had his own "territory", Fishman Island, and so did Bib Mum, "Wholecake Island". So why doesn't Shanks, a fellow younkou, do the same?

Answer (score 7):

These pictures shown Shanks claimed at least one unknown place.

[image: Shanks' flag]
[image: Shanks' flag]

Comment: This could just be a ship or something

Comment: @TGamer added new picture, now it should be clear that it's not a ship